# Is there a limit to the length of HTML attributes?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

How long is too long for an attribute value in HTML?

I'm using HTML5 style data attributes (`data-foo="bar"`) in a new application, and in one place it would be really handy to store a fair whack of data (upwards of 100 characters). While I suspect that this amount is fine, it raises the question of how much is too much?

Comment: For information, one other attribute expected to be _very_ lengthy is `iframe@srcdoc` ([MDN(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) – [HTML5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#element-attrdef-iframe-srcdoc) which contains a whole document (_I heard you liked documents so (…)_)

Answer (score 318, accepted):

HTML5 has no limits on the length of attribute values.

As [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#parsing) says, "This version of HTML thus returns to a non-SGML basis."

Later on, when describing how to parse HTML5, the following passage appears (**emphasis** added):

> The algorithm described below places
> **no limit** on the depth of the DOM tree
> generated, or **on the length of** tag
> names, attribute names, **attribute
> values**, text nodes, etc. While
> implementors are encouraged to avoid
> arbitrary limits, it is recognized
> that practical concerns will likely
> force user agents to impose nesting
> depth constraints.

Therefore, (theoretically) *there is no limit to the length/size of HTML5 attributes*.

<sub>See revision history for original answer covering HTML4.</sub>

Answer (score 176):

I've just [written a test](http://jsbin.com/udiha) (Note! *see update below*) which puts a string of length **10 million** into an attribute and then retrieves it again, and it works fine (Firefox 3.5.2 & Internet Explorer 7)

50 million makes the browser hang with the "This script is taking a long time to complete" message.

**Update**: I've fixed the script: it previously set the innerHTML to a long string and now it's setting a data attribute. https://output.jsbin.com/wikulamuni It works for me with a length of 100 million. YMMV.

```
el.setAttribute('data-test', <<a really long string>>)
```

Comment: wow, holy ....!

Comment: Note that `setAttribute()` tests if  you can set value during runtime. I interpreted the original question to be how much data you can read from the parsed HTML file? That is, the data is in the HTML source and you use e.g. `getAttribute()` to read it.

Answer (score 12):

I really don't think there is any limit. I know now you can do

```
<a onclick=" //...insert 100KB of javascript code here">
```

and it works fine. Albeit a little unreadable.

Answer (score 6):

From [HTML5 syntax doc](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html)

> 9.1.2.3 Attributes
>
> Attributes for an element are
>   expressed inside the element's start
>   tag.
>
> Attributes have a name and a value.
>   Attribute names must consist of one or
>   more characters other than the space
>   characters, U+0000 NULL, U+0022
>   QUOTATION MARK ("), U+0027 APOSTROPHE
>   ('), U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN (>),
>   U+002F SOLIDUS (/), and U+003D EQUALS
>   SIGN (=) characters, the control
>   characters, and any characters that
>   are not defined by Unicode. In the
>   HTML syntax, attribute names may be
>   written with any mix of lower- and
>   uppercase letters that are an ASCII
>   case-insensitive match for the
>   attribute's name.
>
> Attribute values are a mixture of text
>   and character references, except with
>   the additional restriction that the
>   text cannot contain an ambiguous
>   ampersand.
>
> Attributes can be specified in four
>   different ways:
>
> 1. Empty attribute syntax
> 2. Unquoted attribute value syntax
> 3. Single-quoted attribute value syntax
> 4. Double-quoted attribute value syntax

Here there hasn't mentioned a limit on the size of the attribute value. So I think there should be none.

You can also validate your document against the

[HTML5 Validator(Highly Experimental)](http://html5.validator.nu/)

Answer (score 3):

From http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data:

> Every HTML element may have any number of custom data attributes specified, with any value.

That which is used to parse/process these data-* attribute values will have
limitations.

Turns out the data-attributes and values are placed in a DOMStringMap object.
This has no inherent limits.

From http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#domstringmap:

> Note: The DOMStringMap interface definition here is only intended for JavaScript
> environments. Other language bindings will need to define how DOMStringMap is to be
> implemented for those languages

DOMStringMap is an interface with a getter, setter, greator and deleter.
The setter has two parameters of type DOMString, name and value.
The value is of type DOMString that is is mapped directly to a JavaScript String.

From https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/92088-max-allowed-length-javascript-string:

> The maximum length of a JavaScript String is implementation specific.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of any limit on the length of attributes.

In the HTML 4.01 specifications, in the [section on Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) there is nothing that mention any limitation on this.

Same in the [HTML 4.01 DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html) -- in fact, as far as I know, DTD don't allow you to specify a length to attributes.

If there is nothing about that in HTML 4, I don't imagine anything like that would appear for HTML 5 -- and I actually don't see any length limitation in the [9.1.2.3 Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes) section for HTML 5 either.

Answer (score 2):

Tested recently in Edge (Version 81.0.416.58 (64 bits)), and data-attributes seem to have a limit of 64k.

Answer (score 1):

The SGML Defines attributes with a limit set of 65k characters, seen here:
http://www.highdots.com/forums/html/length-html-attribute-175546.html

Although for what you are doing, you should be fine.
As for the upper limits, I have seen jQuery use data attributes hold a few k of data personally as well.

Comment: HTML5 is not an SGML-based language.