# How to display a database message inside a bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

When a user hovers on the element in the table, he should see the message for that element. The message is stored as a property in the model.
This is what I have done so far:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title=@item.Message>Message</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The message is getting displayed inside the tooltip if its just a few characters, but a really long message is not getting displayed.Any idea what should I do?

Comment: It seems to be a limit for the title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516235/max-length-of-title-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though there is a limitation in the number of characters for the `title` attribute in some browsers, it should not affect because you are using the bootstrap tooltip. It should work for long text.

The only problem i can see with your code is, you are not wrapping the text inside single quotes or double quotes. So let's say your item.Message has a value which like `"FirstWord and SecondWord"`, your markup is going to be

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
                                           title=FirstWord and SecondWord>Message</td>
```

So it is going to show only `FirstWord` because there is a space after that.

You should wrap the value of title attribute in quotes and it will work fine.

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="@item.Message">Message</td>
```