# Title attribute does not show complete content

Tags: html, vue.js

I have a div with title attribute with 4000 characters but when I hover over it, it does not show full content. Is there a way to display full content?

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-hugle-mvwu5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `title` length limitation as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29869137/3125477). However, to display all the text you need on hover, you can use existing implementations of tooltips, such as [v-tooltip](https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip). It will be even more appropriate, since `title`

> Represents advisory information for the element, such as would be appropriate for a tooltip. On a link, this could be the title or a description of the target resource; on an image, it could be the image credit or a description of the image; on a paragraph, it could be a footnote or commentary on the text; on a citation, it could be further information about the source; on interactive content, it could be a label for, or instructions for, use of the element; and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

There are limitations in the title attribute,

```
Chrome limits to 1024.
Safari had no limit (I tried up to 3250)
Firefox also had no limit up to 3250.
```