# JSON data into HTML list that looks like a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, recursion

Have nested JSON array and currently trying to create a HTML list ul/li type that also resembles a table.

Here is my JSON data, questions is name of object.

```
{
  "aaData": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "template_id": "1",
      "question": "Is government stable?",
      "answer": "Stable",
      "parent_question_id": "0",
      "section_id": "2",
      "subquestions": [
        {
          "id": "2",
          "template_id": "1",
          "question": "Is there funding approved?",
          "answer": "Since March 2013",
          "parent_question_id": "1",
          "section_id": "2",
          "subquestions": [
            {
              "id": "3",
              "template_id": "1",
              "question": "How much funding do we have?",
              "answer": "120 Million",
              "parent_question_id": "2",
              "section_id": "1"
            },
            {
              "id": "4",
              "template_id": "1",
              "question": "Do we have all raw materials available?",
              "answer": "Not all, need to find correct type of wood.",
              "parent_question_id": "2",
              "section_id": "1"
            },
            {
              "id": "5",
              "template_id": "1",
              "question": "What currency is the funding in?",
              "answer": "GBP",
              "parent_question_id": "2",
              "section_id": "1"
            },
            {
              "id": "6",
              "template_id": "1",
              "question": "When will the currency be paid?",
              "answer": "7 days after invoice",
              "parent_question_id": "2",
              "section_id": "1"
            },
            {
              "id": "13",
              "template_id": "1",
              "question": "why do we do this?",
              "answer": null,
              "parent_question_id": "2",
              "section_id": "1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "7",
          "template_id": "1",
          "question": "What groups are going to investigate?",
          "answer": null,
          "parent_question_id": "1",
          "section_id": "2",
          "subquestions": [
            {
              "id": "8",
              "template_id": "1",
              "question": "What employees have clearance to go?",
              "answer": null,
              "parent_question_id": "7",
              "section_id": "1"
            },
            {
              "id": "9",
              "template_id": "1",
              "question": "Do employees have passports?",
              "answer": null,
              "parent_question_id": "7",
              "section_id": "1",
              "subquestions": [
                {
                  "id": "10",
                  "template_id": "1",
                  "question": "Are employees able to travel?",
                  "answer": null,
                  "parent_question_id": "9",
                  "section_id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "id": "11",
                  "template_id": "1",
                  "question": "Can employees enter without VISA?",
                  "answer": null,
                  "parent_question_id": "9",
                  "section_id": "1"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "template_id": "1",
      "question": "Is market good?",
      "answer": null,
      "parent_question_id": "0",
      "section_id": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is my code, i want just question and answer to show up inside the rows not every element. And would also like to having it looking like a table but with the correct indentations (twitter bootstrap?).

```
function buildHtml( obj , ul ) {

            for (i in obj) {

                console.log(obj[i]);
                //if(i == "question") {
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    li.innerHTML = obj[i];
                    li.className = "list-group-item";
                    //li.style.display = "table-cell";
                    ul.appendChild( li );
                    ul.className = "list-group";
                    //ul.style.display = "table-row";

                    if ( typeof(obj[i])== "object" ) {

                        var childUl = document.createElement('ul');
                        li.appendChild( childUl ); 

                        buildHtml(obj[i], childUl );            
                    } 
                //} 

            }


        } 
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.className = "list-group";
        //ul.style.display = "table-row";
        buildHtml( questions ,ul );
        var div = document.getElementById('test');    
        div.appendChild( ul );
```

......

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

So if anyone has an idea let me know.

Adding how table-like structure should look like:

```
Is government stable? Stable
     Is there funding approved? Since March 2013
           How much funding do we have? 120 Million
           Do we have all raw materials available? Not all, need to find correct type of wood.
           What currency is the funding in? GBP
           When will the currency be paid? 7 days after invoice
           why do we do this?
     What groups are going to investigate?
           What employees have clearance to go?
           Do employees have passports?
                Are employees able to travel?
                Can employees enter without VISA?
Is market good?
```

Comment: Start with renaming id from `"#test"` to `"test"`

Comment: oh yeah sorry i didn't copy and paste that from program did it manually. Look forward to your solution if you have one @Satpal

Comment: does anyone know why it was down voted? There should be no reason as it adheres to standard.

Comment: Not a clue. Three people have voted to close as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem". It would be helpful of those who voted to close would post comments explaining what additional information they feel is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple prototype function to get you started.

```
var Menu = function (data) {
    this.data = data;
};

Menu.prototype.render = function (root) {
    var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
    var li = $("<li></li>");
    li.append($("<a></a>", {
        url: this.data.id,
        text: this.data.question
    })).appendTo(ul);
    ul.appendTo(root);
    if (this.data.subquestions) {
        Menu.renderMenus(this.data.subquestions, $("<li></li>").appendTo(ul));
    }
};

Menu.renderMenus = function (menus, root) {
    $.each(menus, function (key, val) {
        var m = new Menu(val);
        m.render(root);
    });
}

Menu.renderMenus(aaData, $("#test"));
```

### DEMO

You can obviously add more fields to the data where needed.

## **UPDATE**

Per your request to have the nested lists collapsible as seen [here](http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-collapsible-menu-tree-a-practical-example-of-dom-traversing/), I've updated the my original code as well as made some modifications to the code on the site you referenced.

### UPDATED DEMO

Comment: This is great! I think all i want to do after this is to make it a format so I can do a collapse/expand functionality like this page:
http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-collapsible-menu-tree-a-practical-example-of-dom-traversing/
I played around with your code but didn't know where to add that. Any help would be great!

Comment: i added this to end:
$('#test li:has(> ul)').addClass('parent');
So perhaps that might prepare it better add class parent to li?

Comment: @HardFitness - See the **UPDATE** section in my answer.

Comment: excellent, if i wanted to just have the + and - open and close the data rather than click on the question name, should I close the </a> and the just create a div? Basically i want user to click on question and a pop up come up, only plus will make it expand and - collapse. thx

Comment: Yes, anything in the `<a>` will trigger the toggle. If you do not want the text to be part of that then it would need to be moved outside of the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Did that but now the + won't expand when clicked. Just appended to li a div with questions inside. <a href='#'></a><div>question</div>

Comment: @HardFitness - Appending to it will break the recursion because it's looking for `a > ul` to determine if it has a sub-question. I've updated the fiddle [here].(http://jsfiddle.net/t5Hxk/7/)

Comment: that is what i had in mind, but when i add to #tree li > a tag font-size: 12px it then will allow me to click again on questions. Not sure why
#tree li > a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}

Comment: @HardFitness - Try adding `body {font-size:12px;}` to the top of the css section of the fiddle.

Comment: ok works now, had to add it in 2 places on style as something else on my main module was probably overwriting body tag to 16px. I will be now changing this ul/li type table to look like a data table, u have done so much for me thx. So not sure if you have any good links for that to reference?

Comment: @HardFitness - You're welcome, glad I could help. Of course the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) docs are great and so are the ones on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Comment: one last question, how can i make it when you click on the question it does an alert(this.data.question); or some event separate from the + and -? span is now non clickable which is great but i will be adding functionality to make that span clickable and do something. Promise last question!

Comment: @HardFitness - I've updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t5Hxk/8/) to reflect the changes you described. I suggest you study everything I've built so **you** can have a better understanding of the functionality and how to use it for your applications since I won't always be around. It's been a pleasure and Good luck!