# Embedding Json in Scalate

Tags: javascript, json, scalate

I want to embed JSON in the DOM as outlined in the below question:

[Best practice for embedding arbitrary JSON in the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320427/best-practice-for-embedding-arbitrary-json-in-the-dom)

However I can't figure out how to do this with Scalate/Scalatra. I have this in my scaml template:

```
-@ val fullStateJson: String
```

and I can render it via

```
%div= fullStateJson
```

but I can't figure out how to get this into a `<script>`. When I do

```
%script(type="application/json" id="fullStateScript") =fullStateJson
```

It ends up escaped, like

```
{&quot;45&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:45,&quot;level&quot;:0},&quot;98&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:98,&quot;level&quot;:0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TemplateEngine.escapeMarkup` is set to true by default, so it changes the html special characters.

You can put this in your template: `<% escapeMarkup = false %>`