# What is the maximum value that an HTML form element can store

Tags: html

I am wondering what can be the maximum value that a `<input type="hidden">` can store, I am not taking about the maxlength attribute, but the string which it can store.

Comment: What type of form element? A checkbox? `:P`

Comment: `<input>` will be enough to know about.

Comment: Wait, you mean `<input type="checkbox">`? `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas the question did say `<input type="hidden">` all the time, but it was hidden.

Comment: @cloudYturtle Relevant: [Is there a limit to the length of HTML attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496096/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-html-attributes)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It's true though, it needed a couple of backticks.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas thanks, it gave more insight. Couldn't find it while searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/sgmldecl.html

```
 QUANTITY SGMLREF
                  ATTCNT   60      -- increased --
                  ATTSPLEN 65536   -- These are the largest values --
                  LITLEN   65536   -- permitted in the declaration --
                  NAMELEN  65536   -- Avoid fixed limits in actual --
                  PILEN    65536   -- implementations of HTML UA's --
                  TAGLVL   100
                  TAGLEN   65536
                  GRPGTCNT 150
                  GRPCNT   64
```

### edit

according to [html 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090212/tree-construction.html):

> The algorithm described below places no limit on the depth of the DOM
>   tree generated, or on the length of tag names, attribute names,
>   attribute values, text nodes, etc. While implementors are encouraged
>   to avoid arbitrary limits, it is recognized that practical concerns
>   will likely force user agents to impose nesting depth constraints.

Comment: HTML is no longer an application of SGML. The current standard is [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas don't see anything about size limits in that link?

Comment: @Royi Namir , thanks for Edit, I was anyways using HTML 4 but I am not able to locate the "value length"