# data-attributes is there a limit of length and how many?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

Is there a limit on html's data-attribute? Is it possible to have many data-attributes on a tag?

ex. `data-a="" data-b="" data-c="" ... data-z=""`

And also is there a limit how long the value on each data-attribute?

Comment: similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496096/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-html-attributes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a limit to the length of HTML attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496096/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-html-attributes)

Answer (score 5):

> Every HTML element may have **any number** of custom data attributes specified, with any value.

Source: [w3.org: 3.2.5.9 Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-* attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)

The limit of length has been discussed in a previous question linked by Mary Melody above: [Is there a limit to the length of HTML attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496096/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-html-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Far of my concern. Their is no max length when defining data attribute in JavaScript just remember to always use lowercase `[-variable]`