# Any letter limitations for HTML radio button's value?

Tags: forms

I mean may I send large values (50-100 letters) from html radio input ?

Ex :

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="i am sending more letters from here..." />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a limit to the length of HTML attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496096/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-html-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no limits, you should be able to send as much as you want, it's just another form value like a textarea, etc.