# Limit of characters inside tag property

Tags: html

It's a simple question, but I can't find the answer searching.

if I have this:

```
<option value="">Test</option>
```

What's the limit of characters of text that I can put inside the option value? There is a limit? Could I insert a whole `30k` length string inside the value without any consequences (others than readability)? Searching for `maximun` length of a property always brings me to the `max-length` property, instead of what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: It looks like this may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496096/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-html-attributes

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? In general, it should be unlimited or as much as your computer can hold in memory before crashing.

Comment: Yes, that awnser my question, couln't find that question before, thanks and sorry.