# Is there a maximum length for the class name in CSS?

Tags: css

Is there a maximum number of caracters for the name of a class in CSS ?

Comment: All the answers for this go with the spec, but I'd like to know if there's a *practical* limit, for say IE8.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
.thereisnomaximumlengthforaclassnameincss {
maxlength: no;
}
```

Good luck!
There is no maximum length it says.

Comment: this will not validate ... :p

Answer (score 41):

No maxiumum.

Basically, a name may start with an underscore (_), a dash (-), or a letter(a–z), and then be immediately followed by a letter, or underscore, and THEN have any number of dashes, underscores, letters, or numbers:

```
-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*
```

Comment: That explains why I had trouble using a hash as a classname. (SHA, MD5 often start with a number) Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Don't forget about bandwidth. It may not seem to make a difference but one css file with 30 classes with long names can add up to a big performance issue on a large site

Comment: +1, although something tells me that we're not in the 1970s any more, and considering the amount of useless P2P traffic, a few extra UTF8 codepoints in CSS isn't a big deal.

Comment: Bandwidth is also important when using web on a mobile device. Not everyone has a fast mobile connection, and a lot of long names in a huge CSS class can make a difference.

Comment: don't forget about classnames in your html. If you have a table with 1000 rows by 20 cells, then any classname length for TD multiplies by 20,000. So the classname "thereisnomaximumlengthforaclassnameincss" will cost you ~800kb.

Answer (score 2):

W3C Schema for CSS 2.1 -

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/

Also, I used their CSS validator with a really long class name... it passed validation -

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 2):

To add to what others have written, would just like to add if - like me - you find you sometimes end up with crazy long names (because you like being descriptive) then it's worth bearing in mind selectors, which also promotes style re-use and helps keep things easy to read.

e.g.

```
h1 {
   1.5em;
}

styledParagraph {
   font-size: 1em;
}

/* Override the default font size if the styledParagraph element is inside an element with the class articlePage */
.articlePage .styledParagraph {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* Make all <h1> elements in .articlePage -> . styledParagraph larger than the default */
.articlePage .styledParagraph h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

This is very widely supported (even in MSIE 6) and it's much easier to read than a class name like .**articlePageStyleParagraphHeading**.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584184/what-is-a-practical-maximum-length-for-html-id) on ID names in HTML as well.  Seems like there is no "practical" limit.

I say keep them as short as possible, while still being descriptive - why even flirt with crazy-long names? :)