# Is there a limit to how a long the characters of an ID or a class can be  when referencing it inside an HTML element?

Tags: html, css

Is there a limit? This is currently an important matter at hands.

Comment: no, see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192085/is-there-a-maximum-length-for-the-class-name-in-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification imposes no limit.

Most browsers probably do.

At the very least, you will eventually run out of RAM.