# CSS: select a class whose name has a space?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, selector

I have this D3 code which creates my x axis:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(xAxis)
```

How do I select my x axis in my css file? I have:

```
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

But this would apply to all my axes (both x axis and y axis). How do I select only x axis? I know css selectors can be cascaded, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically it is two separate classes, x and axis, but that doesn't mean you can't select and affect only what you want on the x-axis. Cascading selectors looks like this:

```
.x.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Class names](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes) [cannot have spaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens). you have 2 classes if your class name has a space. Use `x-axis` for your class name if you would like to reference it.

> ... none of which are space characters [0]

[0] http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens

Answer (score 1):

For any class with a space:

```
[class*=" "]
{
/* css */
}
```

For `x axis`:

```
[class="x axis"]
{
/* css */
}
```

---

An alternative that doesn't use the CSS attribute selector:

```
.x
{
/* any element with class "x" */
}
.axis
{
/* any element with class "axis" */
}
.x.axis
{
/* any element with classes "x" and "axis"
/* this is what you're after */
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may work, it is a bad idea as `.x`  and `.axis` would also be applicable classes. The overwhelming majority of experienced web developers would see any class attributes with one or more spaces as more than one class.

Comment: I know, but OP gets what OP wants. Maybe he's making something that experienced web devs aren't meant to understand?

Answer (score 0):

@self's comment was correct.  If you have a space between your class name, you then have two class names.

Your code should look like:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis")
  .call(xAxis)
```

CSS:

```
.x-axis {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

The reason you would use two classes is to change an element.  Like this:

```js
$( "#addClass" ).click(function() {
  $( "#box" ).toggleClass("big");
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  }

.big {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="box"></div><button id="addClass">Resize the div</button>
```

I hope this helps you out.  If you have additional questions, ask them below.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are closer than you think. Mutliple classes are seprated by a space. <strike>I also think from memory, class names may need to be more than one character.</strike>  So you could do something like the following

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "horizontal axis")
  .call(xAxis)
```

CSS

```
.axis  line /*Common stuff for both axis*/
{
      fill: none;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis.horizontal line /*Specific to horizonal axis*/
{
   stroke: black;
}

.axis.vertical line /*Specific to vertical axis*/
{
   stroke: red;
}
```

**Note:**  the closest I've been able to find for a source that classes need to be more than one character is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2192121/4665. It quotes no other sources and `.x` [validates](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator). So feel free to use `x` and `y`