# Max length of an HTML attribute value

Tags: html

How would I know what the maximum length of an element's attribute value is?

e.g.

```
<div id="value1..."></div>
```

What's the maximum allowable length for ID attribute of this div and any other attributes of any elements?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496096/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-html-attributes. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584184/what-is-a-practical-maximum-length-for-html-id

Answer (score 18):

According to the [SGML Declaration of HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/sgmldecl.html), the limit could be 65536 characters:

```
ATTSPLEN 65536   -- These are the largest values --
LITLEN   65536   -- permitted in the declaration --
NAMELEN  65536   -- Avoid fixed limits in actual --
PILEN    65536   -- implementations of HTML UA's --
```

The `LITLEN` limits the number of characters which can appear in a single attribute value literal and the `ATTSPLEN` limits the sum of all lengths of all attribute value specifications which appear in a tag.

[Apparently, the limits used to be much lower in HTML 2](https://listserv.heanet.ie/cgi-bin/wa?A2=HTML-WG;3m6KSQ;199501300612250500), and people were complaining back then in 1995.

Comment: 64KB should be more than enough for anyone... Where have I heard that story before?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/527313-maximum-length-html-id-name), technically unlimited.  An actual test in various browsers will show their limits but my guess is the limit would be unreasonably long.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond any practical need.

I use ASP webforms regularly, and often have 100+ character ID's.

Comment: I can imagine 1000+  would come in handy for data-attributes

Comment: Or node-position-ids referring to branches in a tree structure... 64K is the kind of answer I was hoping for  : )

Comment: If I pass JSON in a data-attribute then we could be looking at megabytes.