# Why is my jsonstring in my object undefined?

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following object in my html-site:

```
 <a id="myID" class="list-group-item" href="#"
    title="Cateblalbla." name="Innovation Potential"
    islist="false" type="MetaDataEnum"
    items="[{"id":"Business Innovation","title":"Business Innovation","value":"Business Innovation"},{"id":"Business Differentiation","title":"Business Differentiation","value":"Business Differentiation"},{"id":"Business Standard","title":"Business Standard","value":"Business Standard"}]" stencilsetbindings="[{"order":3,"stencil":"ProcessCollapsed"},{"order":3,"stencil":"BPMNDiagram","namespace":"http://b3mn.org/stencilset/bpmn2.0#"},{"order":5,"stencil":"Task","namespace":"http://b3mn.org/stencilset/bpmn2.0#"}]" glossarybindings="[{"category":"21f8b13544364137aa5e67312fc3fe19","order":5},{"category":"dde0a325cbe84368881a1709384cb37a","order":6}]">
```

And when I do this:

```
console.log(document.id(myID).name)
```

The result is correct.
But when doing it with *.items or .glossaryBindings*, I always get "undefined" why is this the case? I thought its a jsonstring.

**EDIT:**
I create the whole object with javascript dynamically. The items attribute is crated with JSON.stringify(itemArray). So I am not sure how to pretend, that this returns me a jsonstring containing " " quotes instead of  ' '.

Comment: That isn't valid HTML. Aside from the use of non-standard attributes, you're trying to use literal quote characters inside an attribute value delimited with literal quote characters.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Quentin: Do you have an advice how to store an jsonstring in an non-standard attribute without making this 'quote' mistake?

Comment: @texNewbie again what are you trying to accomplish maybe there is a better way to do what you want. You can use `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: @brso05 Problem is that it is dynamically created with JSON.parse(myArray). So how can I pretend getting " ?

Comment: just use single outer quotes for the attribute value and the doubles in the json will be fine

Comment: @charlietfl sadly I can't do that because I use: document.id('myouterDiv').grab(new Element('a'.....

Comment: if it's dynamically created don't set it as attribute....set it as property...problem in html will dissapear

Comment: @charlietfl: sry, how can I do this?

Comment: can use [Element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) but can also add arbitrary properties to an element object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You're using `"` within a `"`-quoted attribute. So naturally the value of the attribute stops as of the first `"` within it.
2. You're using an invalid HTML attribute. To use your own arbitrary attributes, use the `data-` prefix: `data-items="..."` (and `data-stencilset` and `data-type` and...).

To fix #1, you have at least two options:

- Remember that the content of an attribute in HTML is **HTML** text. So to use double-quotes within an attribute value, you can use `&quot;`:

  ```
  data-json="{&quot;foo&qout;:&qout;bar&qout;}"
  ```

  Of course, you also have to remember that `<` and `&` need to be `&lt;` and `&amp;`, too. (But you have to remember that *anyway*, or rely on the browser being tolerant, which it's required to be if it can figure it out.)

  Naturally, you automate that when generating the attribute. It's a simple matter of doing a replacement when writing it: `&` => `&amp;`, `<` => `&lt;`, and `"` => `&quot;` (and again, you should be doing those first two anyway, because the attribute text is HTML regardless of what we're doing here).
- If your value will **never** have `'` in it, you can use `'` around the attribute value instead of `"`:

  ```
  data-json='{"foo":"bar"}'
  ```

**Live Example:**

```js
var attr = document.getElementById("myID").getAttribute("data-items");
var data = JSON.parse(attr);
snippet.log("data[0].id = " + data[0].id);
```

```html
<a id="myID" class="list-group-item" href="#" title="Cateblalbla." name="Innovation Potential" islist="false" type="MetaDataEnum"
data-items="[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;Business Innovation&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Business Innovation&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Business Innovation&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;Business Differentiation&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Business Differentiation&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Business Differentiation&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;Business Standard&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Business Standard&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Business Standard&quot;}]">

  <!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: see my edit: I am not sure how to do your second approach because of the dynamically creating of the attribute

Comment: @texNewbie: What language is the attribute value filled in with? It's a simple matter of doing a replacement when writing it: `&` => `&amp;`, `<` => `&lt;`, and `"` => `&quot;` (and again, you should be doing those first two anyway).

Comment: @texNewbie: And you only have to do that if you're actually writing out HTML text (for instance, when generating an HTML response server-side).

Comment: I still don't know how to change the quotes from my JSON.stringify(itemsArray), whose result I save in an new element which I create with .grab(newElement(...))

Answer (score -1):

You're getting undefined because `items` is not a valid attribute of the `<a>` element. You need to specify it as a data attribute like this:

```
data-items="{json string here}"
```

In Html5 this can be done this way:

```
console.log(document.id(myID).dataset.items);
```

If you're using jquery it can be done this way:

```
console.log($('#' + myID).data("items"));
```

Note: This answer assumes you've addressed the json/html attribute issue ([Best way to store JSON in an HTML attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322682/best-way-to-store-json-in-an-html-attribute))

Second note: Per a comment by @T.J.Crowder, the items attribute is accessible though not through the means used in the question. The proper method of getting a custom attribute is:

```
document.getElementById(myID).getAttribute("items")
```

Comment: That's not why the OP is having the problem they're having. While not valid and not a good idea, non-`data-*` arbitrary attributes do *work*. The quotes are the real problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That looks like the making of an answer. You should post it as such.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How can I fix the quotes problem, when creating the jsonstring with JSON.parse() ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I was tempted to, however I just did a local test on a link using vanilla js, and items shows as undefined regardless. However, there is an alternate method. I'll update for that method.