# Storing a Javascript Object in GAE using Jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

What is the easiest way to save a javascript object to GAE datastore (Python) through Jinja2? I tried looking in the Jinja2 documentation, but I couldn't find any relevant info.  See below for my code and my commentary.  I included an example below that shows where my confusion is. I want to store the javascript variable "Article" as JSON in GAE.  Any help would be  **GREATLY**  appreciated.  Thanks!

**Python**

```
class Post(ndb.Model):
    subject = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    content = ndb.TextProperty(required = True)
    quilljs = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)

class NewPost(PostHandler)
    def post(self):
         subject = self.request.get('subject')
         content = self.request.get('content')
         quilljs = self.request.get('quilljs')
        if subject and content:
             p = Post(parent = blog_key(), subject = subject, content = content, quilljs = quilljs)
            p.put()
```

**HTML**

```
 <form method="post">
      <label>
        <div>subject</div>
        <input type="text" name="subject" value="{{subject}}">
      </label>

      <label>
        <div>blog</div>
        <textarea name="content">{{content}}</textarea>
      </label>
      <div id="quilljs">
          script type="text/javascript">
          var Article = "{{ json_data }}";
          #THIS IS THE PART I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO DO
          </script>
      </div>
      <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322682/best-way-to-store-json-in-an-html-attribute and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193510/how-to-insert-arbitrary-json-in-htmls-script-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using AJAX to pass the JS object over as a JSON object (as well as the other HTML values). Although not the most eloquent solution, it works.