# How to identify the maxlength of HTML ID?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a practical maximum length for HTML id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584184/what-is-a-practical-maximum-length-for-html-id)

What abt the maximum length of the id we use in our html tags?
(eg ) like this how long we give it as the id name?

Answer (score 2):

you can put to **10million character** for the `ID` but it will be difficult to remember.

**50 million** makes the browser hang with the `This script is taking a long time to complete` message.

**100 million** it will kill the tab of your broswer.